# GNs: Rotate Object Instances to fixed reference point 3.2.2

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'd like to rotate my Instances on Points objects so they all face outward from my the center of my geometry.  The default setup has them all facing one way.

I've seen examples of how to do this with Attribute Vector Nodes (https://www.blendernation.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Simon-Thommes-demonstrating-the-use-of-Geometry-Nodes-to-populate-trees-with-leaves-procedurally-with-complete-control-on-orientation-and-scale.-Check-out-his-demonstration-videos-on-this-link.-728x374@2x.jpg), but that has been replaced with a vector math in 3.2.2 and I don't see how to do it since the vector math is very different from the 2.9 Attribute Vector Nodes.

But really my only question is: How can I do this with 3.2.2?  Basically I want my branch segments to go outward from the core of the tree with a tad of randomness.[image]

Maybe I can get the origin point of my tree and put that into an Align Euler to Vector but I do not see how.

Comment: why not using the pivot point of rotate instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basic setup for "track to" geometry origin
[image]